# Casting a derived member of a base array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, casting, derived

I have a base class `Shape` with two derived classes `Circle` and `Rectangle`. Now I have written explicit conversions from `Rectangle` to `Circle` and vice versa. They don't make much sense, but that is not my point right now. I create new `Rectangle` and `Circle` instances, and want to assign the `Rectangle` to the `Circle`with a cast. That works as expected.

But if I have an array of type `Shape`, which is filled with `Rectangles`, and want to cast the member of an array, it throws a `System.InvalidCastException`. As i have written explicit casts, I don't know why this is not possible.

```
Shape[] arr = new Shape[5];

Circle c1 = new Circle(1, 2, 3);
Circle c2 = new Circle(4, 5, 6);
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(7, 8);
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(9, 10);
Shape c3 = new Circle(3, 9, 13);

arr[0] = c1;
arr[1] = c2;
arr[2] = r1;
arr[3] = r2;
arr[4] = c3;


Console.WriteLine(r1.GetType());
Console.WriteLine(arr[2].GetType()); // both evalute to Rectangle

Circle r3 = (Circle)r1;             // compiles
Circle r4 = (Circle)arr[2];         // Unhandled Exception
```

Okay, so as Ondrej pointed out that this is a Cast from Shape to Circle, which is not allowed. However, ingvar pointed out this works:

```
Circle r5 = (Circle)((Rectangle)arr[2]);    
Rectangle r6 = (Rectangle)((Circle)arr[0]);
```

and this doesnt

```
Circle r5 = (Circle)arr[2];   
Rectangle r6 = (Rectangle)arr[0];
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Circle r4 = (Circle)arr[2];
```

The compiler cannot apply the explicit cast, because it cannot statically determine that `arr[2]`, in fact, stores a `Rectangle`. For the compiler, it's `Shape` and hence `(Circle)arr[2]` is a cast from `Shape` to `Circle`.

Comment: This seems logical, but I can't write an explicit cast from Shape to Circle. So my approach is just not possible ?

Comment: Let me suggest you update your question will all declarations including the explicit casts and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your help, and I think I get it now. As the program knows that arr[2] is a Rectangle, I can "cast" it from Shape to Rectangle, and then from Rectangle to Circle. The first cast is not really a cast though, it just works because arr[2] is already a Rectangle

Comment: That's it. Anyway, feel free to post a more comprehensive example and we can discuss further.

Answer (score 0):

You cast element of `Shape` array to `Circle` directly, that's not possible because in fact your object is `Rectangle`. Try explicit cast:

```
Circle r4 = (Circle)((Rectangle)arr[2]);
```

Comment: This works, but why can i cast to Rectangle if I cant cast to circle? Those are both derived classes of Shape, or am I missing something?

Comment: C# doesn't have downcast. You can't directly cast object of base type to object of child type except cases where compiler knows this element type. In your case, compiler knows, that your element is `Rectangle`, so it allows to convert it to `Rectangle`